# How to create a menu separator in pystray

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, separator, pystray

I am trying to create a pystray menu separator, but I am having a hard time doing so. I have searched here on SO and in its [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pystray/stable/pystray.pdf), which I find super confusing and unhelpful and I even tried to read the `Menu` class:

```py
class Menu(object):
    """A description of a menu.

    A menu description is immutable.

    It is created with a sequence of :class:`Menu.Item` instances, or a single
    callable which must return a generator for the menu items.

    First, non-visible menu items are removed from the list, then any instances
    of :attr:`SEPARATOR` occurring at the head or tail of the item list are
    removed, and any consecutive separators are reduced to one.
    """
    #: A representation of a simple separator
    SEPARATOR = MenuItem('- - - -', None)

    def __init__(self, *items):
        self._items = tuple(items)
```

In which I found the following representation, which I used like this:

```py
sep = pystray.MenuItem("- - - -", None)
```

but instead of creating a separator, it created a menu item with this text: `- - - -`

You can find a minimal reproducible example below:

```
import pystray
from PIL import Image
def item1_action(icon, item):
    print("Item 1 clicked")
def item2_action(icon, item):
    print("Item 2 clicked")
def quit_action(icon, item):
    print("Quit clicked")

item1 = pystray.MenuItem("Item 1", item1_action)
item2 = pystray.MenuItem("Item 2", item2_action)
sep = pystray.MenuItem("- - - -", None)
quit_item = pystray.MenuItem("Quit", quit_action)
menu = (item1, item2,s, quit_item)
image = Image.open('icon.png')
icon = pystray.Icon("test", image, "test", menu)
icon.run()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have correctly identified the point at which the use of the separator is indicated. However, you should specifically use the `SEPARATOR` attribute instead of its assigned value because someone might actually want to create a menu item with four hyphens, and it wouldn't be appropriate for **pystray** to automatically convert it to a separator against their will.

That being said, you need to replace this:

```py
sep = pystray.MenuItem("- - - -", None)
```

with this:

```py
sep = pystray.Menu.SEPARATOR
```

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I've actually used this library a few times, so I had a bit of a head start. :D

Comment: Ohhh... so close... thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @aurorathorn You are most welcome!